# Loop through and match duplicates

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through a array with emailaddresses like this:
array (

1. hi@example.com, orderitem 1, orderitem 2
2. goodbye@example.com, orderitem 5, orderitem 3
3. hello@example.com, orderitem 3, orderitem 2
4. hi@example.com, orderitem 3, orderitem 5
   )

and if there is a match get all orderitems for the address.
Should return:

1. hi@example,
   orderitem 1, orderitem, 2, orderitem 3, orderitem 5
2. goodbye@example.com, orderitem 5, orderitem 3

and so on.

```
        foreach ($orders as $key => $value) { 
        $email = $value->getEmail(); 

        $emailArr = [$email];
        var_dump($emailArr);

        if(isset($this->$email) == $emailArr) {

        

    //   if(isset($email) == $email) {
    //         // echo '<div>' . $email . '</div>';
            $orderItems = $value->getOrderItems();
            foreach($orderItems as $item) {
                echo '<div>string is match</div>';
                echo '<div>' . $item->getName() . '</div>';
            }
         } else {
            echo '<div>nothing to show</div>';
```

I've tried many different approaches but nothing seems to do the acctual compare/match. This is a exercise and everything is hardcoded but that should work anyway.

I'm kind of new to PHP but searched throught the webb and tried out, in_array(), trim() etc. Nothing works, but probably just a beginners mistake

Comment: The example array you gave is not a valid array in PHP. Please provide an example of the actual array so that we may see each individual element.

Comment: `isset()` returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `$emailArr` outside your loop. Then append each item to it.

```
$emailArr = array(); // define here
foreach ($orders as $key => $value) { 
    $email = $value->getEmail();
    if(in_array($email, $emailArr)) {
          // skip or do something else
        echo "Matched";
    }
    else {
        array_push($emailArr, $email);
        // do other stuff
        echo "added new";
    }
}
```